# SQL query on percentage share of different groups in total

Tags: sql, postgresql

I could barely get this to work... It seems there is redundancy as the dates are repeated twice, for example. Is there a way to simplify it?

```
WITH total AS 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(type) AS total FROM loan_loan
    WHERE 
      loan_loan.created_at > '2019-08-15' and 
      loan_loan.created_at < '2019-09-05'
  )
SELECT 
  type, 
  COUNT(*), 
  (0.00 + COUNT(*)) / total.total as share
FROM loan_loan, total
WHERE 
  loan_loan.created_at > '2019-08-15' and 
  loan_loan.created_at < '2019-09-05'
GROUP BY 
  type, 
  total.total
```

It (correctly) returns a table like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         type        |       count      |       share      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         type1       |        26        |       0.52       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         type2       |        24        |       0.48       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: Could you tell us what this is supposed to do? Also, you have DDL statements?

Answer (score 1):

### CTEs

A CTE is an optimization fence. You'll want to try to avoid it and at the least convert it into a subquery.

### Casting

Do an explicit cast instead of an implicit cast:

```
0.00 + COUNT(*)
```

becomes

```
count(*)::real
```

### Between

Rather than writing

```
  loan_loan.created_at > '2019-08-15' and 
  loan_loan.created_at < '2019-09-05'
```

write

```
  loan_loan.created_at between '2019-08-15' and '2019-09-05'
```

### Joining

More broadly: are you sure this is doing the right thing? You aren't selecting `type` from your CTE to join to your upper query's `loan_loan.type`. Given the lack of this join, I fail to see how your `total` column will be reliably matched to your upper rows.

Comment: Regarding joining, this is all from one table: `loan_loan`, so should be OK, right?

Comment: Nope :) the moment that you do two different select statements, they create two different "virtual" tables that you need to join together.